# ORA-00904: "EVENTPLAN"."LINENO": invalid identifier 00904. 00000 - "%s: invalid identifier" *Cause: *Action: Error at Line: 16 Column: 5

Tags: sql, oracle

For each event plan, list the plan number, count of the event plan lines, and sum of the number of resources assigned. For example, plan number “P100” has 4 lines and 7 resources assigned. You only need to consider event plans that have at least one line.

---

Here is my answer for this :

```
select DISTINCT planno, count(lineno),  sum(resno)
from eventplanline, eventplan, resourcetbl
where resourcetbl.resno = eventplanline.resno
and eventplan.lineno =eventplanline.lineno;
```

Comment: Just a wild guess; you don't have the column LINEBO in the table EVENTPLAN?

Comment: thanks dude. I just notice it hiihihi :D.

Comment: Missing `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN`! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Answer (score 0):

> **`ORA-00904`** error message is a invalid identifier message.

`SQL` statement that included an invalid column name or referance an invalid alias get an probably `ORA-00904` error. Please check `EVENTPLAN` table has contains `LINENO` column.